# Training neural networks on very large sparse matrices in pytorch

Tags: python, pytorch, sparse-matrix, large-data

I have a dataset with about 74 million observations. Each of these observations is represented by ~1,000 features and labelled with up to ~3,200 binary classes. Most individual observations are labelled with no more than ~10 classes, so the labels are very sparse. Currently, the label and feature matrices are stored in MatrixMarket format.

I'd like to train a neural network on the 74m * 1000 input matrix to predict the 74m * 3200 labels. However, this obviously won't fit into memory. This is my first time working with a dataset this big. So far, the options I can see include:

- write each set of features and labels to a text file individually, and sample items in each minibatch randomly from a list of files (seems inefficient)
- use pandas to iterate through a single CSV file [chunk-by-chunk](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/io.html#iterating-through-files-chunk-by-chunk)
- I have also seen zarr, WebDataset and TensorStore discussed but I can't tell if these are a good fit for this problem

Any advice on the best way to approach this problem for someone that doesn't have a lot of experience working with datasets that don't fit in memory?

Comment: Have you ever try mini-batch training process. A well-known method that is usually used for a big dataset in both industry and research

Comment: My question is about how to load minibatches of this very dataset into memory.

Comment: Ah, your second way might work. But with a small suggestion that, you also need to write a similar class like the [ImageFolder](https://pytorch.org/vision/main/generated/torchvision.datasets.ImageFolder.html)

For more specific, you need to create a DataLoader. At every batch, this loader will read the data from your file and save your data into your memory, when everything is done, the Loader will load **another batch** to the same allocated memory on your RAM. That might work

Comment: You can write your own batch loader in Pytorch. I'm not sure how the input is stored ... is it one massive file or a ton of small files? If it's one large file you can use memmap() to memory map the input and read N gigabytes at time, train on that data then fetch the next N GBs. As long as your training takes longer than loading N GBs, you can load two or more chunks at a given time (called pre-fetching or double buffering). You can then pass a chunk to your model to train on while you load the next chunk

Answer (score 1):

To deal with dataset size, use a library like [datasets](https://huggingface.co/docs/datasets/index) that doesn't require you to load into memory.

If you want to go further, you can convert your data from dense to sparse where you only track the ID of present classes.

For example, `[0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]` would become `[2, 8]`